# Snapcraft is downloading Ubuntu files

Tags: compiling, packaging, snap

Just tried creating a snap yesterday for an application and failed miserably, I will go at it this evening after work. 
What bugs me though is the Ubuntu directory which gets created and where more than 200mb of Ubuntu files get's downloaded, any ideea why?
I even tried with the basic hello snap yaml from snapcraft website but still same result.

Anyone has any ideea why?

Comment: All depending on what are you trying to package and how (std `build` or `cleanbuild`) .  Could you add more details: instructions your following (links) , some logs .. any thing that can help us see what you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, these are called "stage packages," and you can read more about them [here](https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/blob/master/docs/snapcraft-syntax.md), but real quickly:

Snapcraft has the ability to utilize .debs in two ways-- you can specify them as "build-packages" or "stage-packages" in the YAML per part. Build packages are debs installed on the host system (it really just calls `apt install` for you) in order to facilitate building, but don't make it into the final snap (although some libraries may be taken due to elf crawling). Stage packages get downloaded and unpacked directly into the root of the snap.

Comment: It downloaded 500+ mb of packages only to fail miserable.

Comment: That will of course depend on what you're trying to snap. Please feel free to hop into #snappy on freenode to work on it together, or shoot an email to the mailing list!